# iTunes: Associate transaction_id with an email receipt from a user

Tags: ios, api, itunes, payment

From time to time we receive user support requests where the user complains that they did not receive their item in our game.

In our database we are logging the transaction_id returned by the iTunes API whenever we issue a purchase. So in theory we can verify if a user has received their item or not, based on the field transaction_id.

However the transaction_id seems to be pretty useless. Whenever users send us a copy of the email receipt by Apple or send us a screenshot from their iTunes purchase history, they include order number or document number, but none of those matching the format of the transaction ids.

How can we associate any given receipt email from Apple with transaction_ids in our database, so our user support team can verify if a purchase has already been handled or not?

Comment: Unless the user is registering an account in your server and can tell you their account name, then there is no way you can correlate a transaction against a specific user.